# unable to install any software or updates in UBUNTU 13.04

Tags: software-installation

> Linux balu-System-Product-Name 3.8.0-23-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29   >20:24:54 UTC 2013 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux

I frequently get this type of error when installing software:

```
dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic
```

I tried installing VLC through software centre and through the terminal.

1) software centre

```
Removing linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic ... /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic.postrm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic.postrm: Syntax error: ")" unexpected 
dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic (--remove): 
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2 
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already 
Errors were encountered while processing: 
linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic 
Error in function:
```

2) Terminal

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'oracle-java7-installer' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 302933 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic.postrm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic.postrm: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please answer me. Sorry for the previous posts; I have deleted them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not updated your system which you can do it by typing the command `sudo apt-get update`

Then you can install anything like VLC, or cheese etc using the command like `sudo apt-get install vim vlc cheese ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: Absolutely the first thing to try.

Comment: I tried that but no use.Software updater still not showing the New Release.Thnx.